# Running linux command by its absolute file path

Tags: linux, command

[image: output]I know that we can invoke the Unix or Linux command by its absolute file path as well as the command itself. For instance we can list directory contents by typing `ls` as well as `/bin/ls` (in Linux) **Is there any difference?**. When i do this i got the same output but only difference in its color separation between file types you can see that in uploaded image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Giving the command `ls` at the prompt would do a bit more than just call `/bin/ls`.  If `ls` was an alias or a function, that alias or function would be called.  If it was neither, and if it furthermore was not a built-in command (`ls` is very rarely a built-in command), then a path search would be performed for `ls` in each directory in the `:`-delimited list in the `$PATH` environment variable.

The `ls` that was *first* found in `$PATH` would be executed.  This could potentially be another `ls` than `/bin/ls` if a directory that contained such a name was located earlier than `/bin` in the `$PATH` list.

Using `/bin/sh` would bypass the alias and function lookups as well as any lookups in `$PATH` and would instead run that command directly.

The difference in colour in the output between `ls` and `/bin/ls` could possibly be explained by `ls` being an alias that adds extra command line options when invoking the `ls` utility (check with `alias ls` or `type -a ls` in `bash`).